# Asp.Net WebApi Custom Media Formatter not matching a particular type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm checking out web api's content negotiation and custom formatters and trying to use a generic custom formatter. Using RazorEngine I am parsing a razor view to be returned as a response message from a web api controller.

Here is my formatter configuration

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new RazorViewFormatter<DefaultViewModel>("home-json", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json"), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new RazorViewFormatter<DefaultViewModel>("home", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new RazorViewFormatter<IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>>("categories-json", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json"), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new RazorViewFormatter<IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>>("categories", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")));
```

Making a request with to my default resource, returns the correctly parsed razor view.

```
GET http://localhost:56071/api/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Accept: text/json
Host: localhost:56071
```

However making a request to my categories resource, just returns the serialized json of my model rather than the parsed template. Essentially missing the mark the on custom media formatter. WriteToStreamAsync() is never called

```
GET http://localhost:56071/api/categories HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Accept: text/json
Host: localhost:56071
```

Is this not a workable approach?  I do get a match on CanReadType, I'm wondering if the multiple formatters and they way conneg is evaluated ends up somehow not matching text/json.

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**

```
public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
{
    return (type == typeof (T) || type.IsSubclassOf(typeof (T)));
}

public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your CanReadType?  The last two formatters both map to IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> so I'm not sure how you would choose between the two.  Also, it should be application/json not text/json really.

Comment: I take a slightly more brute force way of doing a Razor formatter  https://github.com/darrelmiller/HypermediaApiSite/blob/master/HypermediaApiSiteConsole/Tools/ViewEngineFormatter.cs